# Compile issue ld: Unsatisfied symbol

Tags: c++, acc

I am trying to compile a C++ application on HP server (HP-UX rx6600 B.11.23)  using the compiler `/usr/bin/cc`:

```
HP aC++/C for Itanium(R)-based systems B3910B A.05.50 [May 15 2003].
```

While compiling I am getting the below error:

```
ld: Unsatisfied symbol "ucnv_open_4_2" in file XalanCtrl.o
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which is the line you use to compile and/or link that application? For the message, it seems that you need to link against some library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed after replacing the unicode folder with the version 2.6 and not 4.2 as displayed in the error.
The bianry is generated now.

Thanks

Best Regards